# Facebook ID - find it with a given profile link

Tags: facebook

Given following `https://www.facebook.com/name` I want to find out the public facebook id. It can be done here: http://findmyfbid.com/

Actually, I want to integrate that directly in my android app, can anyone say how the author of this page did it?

**Why do I need it?**

My app allows a user to sync phone contact pictures with the profile pictures of there facebook friends. Due to API changes, apps can't retrieve a list of all friends anymore. Displaying a list of friends that use the same app is senseless! So I want the user to be able to at least insert there friends manually into my app...

**Edit**

I found a way to do it. And I don't understand why someone would down vote this simple question. It's just a simple technical question. That it is not supported by Facebook is no reason for down voting IMHO...

Comment: Read about of App-scoped ID's: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#scoped_ids

Comment: I know them. Not usable for my usecase. I have a root method that already works, but I want to add a non root method...

Comment: as you can read in my answer, it´s not allowed to do that and there is no other way. what for do you need the real id anyway? you are not allowed to store it or use it in any way without the consent of the user, so you could just authorize him and use the app scoped id instead.

Comment: I edited my question and explained the use case...

Comment: well, that use case is not allowed. you are not supposed to get any data (or pictures) of user friends if they did not authorize the app too. the only way would be scraping, and that is not allowed at all.

Comment: actually, from my point of view, that does not really make sense. If the person has a public page, I can always view the persons picture and name. So this should be available to apps (as it is available to browsers as well)... but anyway, I know what you mean...

Answer (score 1):

It can only be done by parsing/scraping the profile page, which is not allowed. You are not supposed to use the public ID in any way anymore, just let users authorize and grab their App Scoped ID.

There are also other endpoints like `taggable_friends` and `invitable_friends`, but you are not allowed to use those for your use case.